# Why can't I edit queries in data explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits, data-explorer

The [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) has many queries, but I can't seem to be able to extend a query that's already there.
If I see a nice query that I want to extent I have to duplicate it and save a copy, adding to the noise on data explorer.

Why isn't data explorer more like the rest of stack*.com, where I can edit stuff, and vote to keep or rollback edits.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are no edit rights because there is no privileges system on SEDE. There is an admin role, but I think that's hard coded in the database right now.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot edit queries that are not yours.

But you can click "fork query" to make a new copy of it and eventually improve it. Then save it into your query pool.

Comment: -1 I know that it says so in the question, I want to be able to edit whatever query and if 5 people vote on that then the query is changed.

Comment: The query does NOT belong to you. I don't want anybody changing queries I use for my own sake. Maybe edit suggestion could be a good idea.